# Using QualifierFilter leads to only returning matched columns

Tags: java, hbase

If I apply any other kind of filter, my Scan returns all columns by default. If I use `QualifierFilter` then only the columns that are matched by the filter are returned. I even tried `scan.addFamily` and explicitly adding `scan.addColumn` but no other columns are returned. Is there a way to get all columns while making a match based on `QualifierFilter`.

My code looks like this

```
FilterList filters = new FilterList();
filters.addFilter(new QualifierFilter(CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(b(tsToKey(start)))));
filters.addFilter(new QualifierFilter(CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(b(tsToKey(end)))));
filters.addFilter(new PageFilter(MAX_ROWS));

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(filters);
scan.addFamily(getFamily()); // doesnt helps
```

The results from the scan only include the columns with timestamps matched by the filter. I have other static columns in this table which are not returned by this scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A QualifierFilter is used exclusively to filter based on the column qualifier. So it is doing its job. :)  Please add your requirement properly.

Comment: I understand what the QualifierFilter is doing. I do want to filter rows based on match made by the Qualifier but for the rows that the match is made, I would like the scanner to return the complete row. Instead, its only returning the row key and the columns that matched the filter (in the result object). For other filters such as `SingleColumnValueFilter` this is not the case. The result object contains all columns, not just the one matched by the filter. Any ideas how I can retrieve all columns of the matched rows.

Comment: SingleColumnValueFilter returns the rows which match a specific column qualifier to a value. It returns the entire row. But here the QualifierFilter is to be used when you need only specific columns. Your requirement is having two contradictory things if I am not wrong. let me know if I got your requirement.

Comment: Okay so is there simply no way to retrieve full row while making a match based on qualifier name.

Comment: Qualifier here means a specific column cell. So is your requirement to retrieve a row based on column value? Or to retrieve a row and just a few columns. See the links, which might help you in different combinations [link](http://www.hadooptpoint.com/filters-in-hbase-shell/) or [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html)

Comment: My requirement is to retrieve a row based on column name, not column value. It sounds like that might not be possible. In that case, I might have to do another scan to get full row based on obtained row keys from the first column name based scan.

Comment: Actually after you get row keys, you should use a multi get operation, not another scan.